# Creating a document in ElasticSearch using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, in fact I just started learning it today. What i am trying to achieve now is to index a document using basic HttpWebRequest and Stream in C#
This is my code

```
 public static void Invoke<O>(string uri, string Method, O data)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateRequest<O>(uri, Method, data);
        request.GetResponse();
    }


    private static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest<O>(string uri, string Method, O data)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = Method;
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        if (data != null)
        {
            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data.XmlSerializeToString());
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Send the data.
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }


        return request;
    }
```

But i am getting response as bad request.

When i try in RESTClient by giving the URL and JSON of the xml, it is getting saved.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This is the data that i am passing to the CreateRequest method
<Node>
  <changeset>2015-12-01 12:06+05:30</changeset>
  <id>1</id>
  <registerid>1</registerid>
</Node>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue , by converting the xml to json before converting to byte array .